# How can I hide and unhide images with one UIButton. Swift

Tags: swift

I would like to hide these images and unhide them with the same button. Right now I have 2 actions attached to one button. A Touch Down and a Touch Down repeat. The Touch Down repeat makes me press the button twice to unhide the images. I would just like to press it once to unhide as in when I press to hide. Anyone any idea on how to handle this?

```
@IBAction func settingsCheck(sender: UIButton) {
    c.hidden = true
    d.hidden = true
    e.hidden = true
    f.hidden = true
    g.hidden = true
    a.hidden = true
    b.hidden = true
    cFour.hidden = true
    settingsCheck.hidden = false
}

@IBAction func settingCheckButtonsUnhide(sender: UIButton) {
    c.hidden = false
    d.hidden = false
    e.hidden = false
    f.hidden = false
    g.hidden = false
    a.hidden = false
    b.hidden = false
    cFour.hidden = false
    settingsCheck.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: Use logic. Do you know about the magic word `if`? `if` they are hidden, show them; `if` they are showing, hide them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just use ! in front of the actual hidden state as follow to invert it:

```
@IBAction func settingsCheck(sender: UIButton) {
     c.hidden = !c.hidden
     d.hidden = !d.hidden
     e.hidden = !e.hidden
     f.hidden = !f.hidden
     g.hidden = !g.hidden
     a.hidden = !a.hidden
     b.hidden = !b.hidden
     cFour.hidden = !cFour.hidden
}
```

Comment: Thank you Leonardo ! That's another great way to get the job done ! Appreciate the help !

Comment: Yeah, this way is actually smarter. +1 for you @Leonardo!

Answer (score 0):

As @matt suggests in the comments, you can use:

```
@IBAction func settingsCheck(sender: UIButton) {

if c.hidden == false {
 c.hidden = true
 d.hidden = true
 e.hidden = true
 f.hidden = true
 g.hidden = true
 a.hidden = true
 b.hidden = true
 cFour.hidden = true}

else {
c.hidden = false
d.hidden = false
e.hidden = false
f.hidden = false
g.hidden = false
a.hidden = false
b.hidden = false
cFour.hidden = false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you CeceXX! Appreciate your help !